# order non-null values of firstTimestamp ASC, then order the null values after that with secondTimestamp DESC

Tags: sql

I have an object that looks like this ->

`{
   firstTimestamp, 
   secondTimestamp
 }`

I would like to do the following

- First, order all values that have firstTimestamp ASC, NULLS LAST
- Then order the nulls with secondTimestamp, descending

How would I go about doing this in sql?

I'm thinking something like ->

```
                             ORDER BY
                               first_timestamp ASC NULLS LAST,
                               second_timestamp DESC
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of SQL, something like this may work...

```
Order By
    Case When first_timestamp is null then 1 Else 0 End ASC,
    first_timestamp ASC,
    second_timestamp DESC
```